# I'm trying to grab the value after the tag and the value is not in the tag in puppetter

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to grab [this color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvFLg.png) from [this webpage](https://www.chinyere.pk/collections/top-shirt/products/aa3998) with puppeteer. But I'm having issues to scrape that color correctly.

```
const productColor_Selector = '.lang1 p:nth-of-type(1)'
const productColor = await page.$eval(productColor_Selector, e => e.textContent)

console.log("color", productColor)

let colorFilter = productColor;
let splitColor = colorFilter.split('Color:');
let colorProduct = splitColor[1].trim().split(' ')[1];

console.log("Final Color:", colorProduct)
```

As a result of running my code sometimes I get color but it is in a bad format and sometimes it returns as `undefined`: [see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9enCf.png)

Comment: Don't post relevant stuff as image -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ali, please don't forget to upvote the helpful answers and accept an answer as solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const colorProduct = await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelectorAll('.lang1 p:nth-of-type(1) strong')[1]
          .nextSibling.nodeValue
);
```

Comment: Thanks you soo much sir! Its works Perfectly Fine :)